# Hive table not having the same data as HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

The data from HDFS does not match the data in hive table. I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `user_id` bigint,
  `type` int
)ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I am executing two inserts:

```
val table = "tbl"
firstData.insertInto(table, false)
secondData.insertInto(table, false)
```

There are two files created in HDFS - `000000_0` and `000001_0` - one containing the first set of data, another the second. It's correct, but when I do:

`hive -e 'SELECT * FROM tbl' > '/tmp/output_tbl.csv'`

I'm getting only the first data set. What's wrong? Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: can you pls post the sample hadoop fs -cat of 000000_0 and 0000001_0

may be your second data set have different format

Comment: It has the same format - text (csv)